# Find matching sequence of items in a list

Tags: python, list

Here is a test list :

```
test_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How can I check if this list contains exactly thoses values 1,2,3 in this order (nothing in between values) ?

In this example, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] contains '1,2,3' but doesn't contain '4,5,8' because there are items between 5 and 8, neither '3,2,1' because they are not in this order.

I guess this problem is easy to solve but I cannot find a nice and fast way to do it... Please, could you give me some clue? Kindly

Comment: Would you like to share your code, and where is you think need to be improved?

Comment: we can convert the list into a string and search for substr, KMP algorithm to the rescue ! makes sense in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate 3 consecutive elements together and use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check whether any of the match is `True`. For example:

```
>>> my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> my_num = (1, 2, 3)

>>> any(x== my_num for x in zip(my_list, my_list[1:], my_list[2:]))
True
```

Refer below documents for more details:

- [`zip()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`any()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to extend this to find any ‘pairs’ of consecutive numbers?

Comment: Yes, you can do like this `any(x==my_num for x in zip(*(my_list[i:] for i in range(len(my_num)))))`. But it is not worth it. If your tuple length is dynamic, Aven's answer is better

Answer (score 2):

```py
def list_contains(A, B): 
    n = len(A) 
    return any(A == B[i:i + n] for i in range(len(B)-n + 1))
```

```py
#Example
test_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list_contains([1,2,3], test_list) # True
list_contains([4,5,8], test_list) # False
```

Comment: `any` is handy and powerful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip to form subsets and check if your sequence is present in those.

Here is a generalized way to do it:

```
L = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
S = [1,2,3]

if tuple(S) in zip(*(L[i:] for i in range(len(S)))):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Using parameter unpacking `*(...` gives zip as many sub-lists as there are elements in `S`.  Each of these sublist starts at a different offset so zip will receive L[0:],L[1:],L[2:],... which will form tuples with every sublist of length `len(S)`.

If you don't want to use zip(), you can use indexes to form the subsets:

```
if S in (L[i:i+len(S)] for i in range(len(L))):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

The string strategy requires that the separator avoids overstepping boundaries (e.g. not finding "1,2,3" in "11,2,31").  This can be achieved by using "][" as the separator so that all values are enclosed in the same way ("[1][2][3]" in "[11][2][31]"):

```
if str(S).replace(", ","][") in str(L).replace(", ","]["):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

While this works on numeric values, it can still fail if the values are strings (which may contain any pattern including the string version of the sequence).

Comment: Just run a simple `performance` comparison between this and @Aven's  and find out this is much faster:  wondering what's the contributing factors.

Comment: I think it may be because the string approach relies on low level code for most of the work as opposed to the other ones that perform Python code in a loop (including generating list/tuples for subsets). BTW I change the string strategy condition (the previous one was missing the enclosing brackets)

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, I've run a small performance comparison to see which one is faster for larger list (over 1+ million numbers). Here is the results:

```
import time

def list_contains(S, L):
    ''' check if S in in L - list of integers'''
    
    n = len(S)
    return any(S == L[i:i + n] for i in range(len(L)-n + 1))

# @AlainT version
def list_in_list(S, L):
    if tuple(S) in zip(*(L[i:] for i in range(len(S)))):
        return f'True'
    
    return f'False'




if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = L = list(range(1, 1_000_000))

    start_time = time.time()
    S = [567_899, 567_900, 567_901]
    
    list_contains(S, L)     # 0.1557  ** use any(..) from @Anoymous's got almost same results
    #list_in_list(S, L)     # 0.0528

    print('....%s seconds', (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```py
def contains(sarr,sseq):
    return sseq in sarr
arr = [1,2,3,4,4,5,7,8]
seq = [1,2,3]
print(contains(''.join(map(str, arr)),''.join(map(str, seq))))
```